# Issue with pyspark windowing function

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe like this

| Id | TimeStamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 10:15 | 10 |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 10:30 | 20 |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 10:45 | 40 |
| 2 | 01/01/2023 10:15 | 15 |
| 2 | 01/01/2023 10:30 | 25 |
| 2 | 01/01/2023 10:45 | 35 |

and the output should be

| Id | StartTimeStamp | Starting Reading | EndTimeStamp | End Reading |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 10:15 | 10 | 01/01/2023 10:30 | 20 |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 10:30 | 20 | 2001/01/2023 10:45 | 40 |
| 2 | 01/01/2023 10:15 | 15 | 01/01/2023 10:30 | 25 |
| 2 | 01/01/2023 10:30 | 25 | 01/01/2023 10:45 | 35 |

I am trying window function, however its looking  for aggregation which is not possible. Any other options i can use to do this using pyspark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that window functions still may be usefull here, check my solution with lag

Please note that i am removing first row by notNull filter, if this column is nullable you may need to adjust this code to drop first row in a different way

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
import datetime

df = [
    {"id": 1, "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 15), "value": 10},
    {"id": 1, "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 30), "value": 20},
    {"id": 1, "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 45), "value": 40},
    {"id": 2, "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 15), "value": 15},
    {"id": 2, "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 30), "value": 25},
    {"id": 2, "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 45), "value": 35},
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("timestamp")

df.withColumn(
    "start_reading",
    (F.coalesce(F.lag("value").over(windowSpec), F.lit(0))),
).withColumn("end_reading", F.col("value")).withColumn(
    "start_timestamp",
    (F.coalesce(F.lag("timestamp").over(windowSpec), F.lit(None))),
).withColumn(
    "end_timestamp", F.col("timestamp")
).filter(
    F.col("start_timestamp").isNotNull()
).drop(
    "timestamp",
    "value"
).show()
```

output

```
+---+-------------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
| id|start_reading|end_reading|    start_timestamp|      end_timestamp|
+---+-------------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|           10|         20|2023-01-01 10:15:00|2023-01-01 10:30:00|
|  1|           20|         40|2023-01-01 10:30:00|2023-01-01 10:45:00|
|  2|           15|         25|2023-01-01 10:15:00|2023-01-01 10:30:00|
|  2|           25|         35|2023-01-01 10:30:00|2023-01-01 10:45:00|
+---+-------------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
```